# Query return speed is fine but fetch is very slow

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

PostgreSQL 14

PHP 7.4

I have a PHP call that returns a handle to a scrollable cursor (PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL) with about 760,000 records. The handle is being returned in a reasonable amount of time. However, once I have the handle back, doing nothing but fetching each record in a loop is taking over 12 minutes. I have tried it as a forward-only cursor with similar results. I am on high performance processors and have plenty of memory. Each record has 181 numeric fields. How can I improve the performance of this?

```
$first = true;
while($rec = $handle->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, $first ? PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST : PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT))
{
    $first = false;
}
```

Updates to answer questions:

> Network distance between client and server?

Zero. Both are on localhost.

> Where is the return time being measured in the database layer or an application frontend?

Measured from the time the query is executed to when the handle is returned. Getting the handle is fine. It's the fetch loop itself that is taking forever once it starts. PHP is measuring the fetch loop execution time.

> Do you need to fetch one by one or can you fetch in batches?

I could fetch in batches and process the batches one by one, but the base query is very heavy and running it repeatedly to get to an offset would not be good.

Comment: Network distance between client and server? Where is the return time being measured in the database layer or an application frontend? Do you need to fetch one by one or can you fetch in batches? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: If you are using the Postgres cursor then [FETCH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) allows you to do "FORWARD count Fetch the next count rows. FORWARD 0 re-fetches the current row."

Comment: Is that any faster? I tested this with a simple forward-only cursor - no special options - and had the same speed issues.

Comment: I don't program in PHP so I have no way of testing. Still I would expect there to be a performance improvement going from 760,000 iterations to some lesser number.  Say if you do a count of 1000, then 760 iterations.

Comment: How long does it take to run the save query in psql, with EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)?

Comment: Take a look at the PG configuration parameters, to know if it is configured to make full use of the memory and cpu cores that your server is having. See this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186766)

Comment: I suspect that your query has a small startup cost - that's why you start to get results quickly,  but big total cost - that's why all query takes a long time. But to be sure - you need to EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) your query. If you can't dissect query from php source - look in `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_stat_statements`.

Comment: Folks it is a server side cursor that is being fetched one record at a time.  Do the math: 12 minutes x 60 = 720 seconds. 720 seconds/ 760,000 records = 0.00095 sec/record. The issue is not on the server side, it is the number of iterations being done on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your statement on a `psql` command line.

If it is slow there as well, you have to use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to understand why (and add the execution plan to the question for further help).

If it is fast in `psql`, the problem are either the 760000 client-server round trips or that you didn't set `cursor_tuple_fraction` to 1.0.

Comment: The combination of the cursor_tuple_fraction setting and batching provided significant improvement. Thanks everyone!